# LoopBack Android SDK Login Error

Tags: android, rest, authentication, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am currently using Strongloop Android SDK attempting to do a basic userlogin on my local machine. When I attempt to connect to localhost at 10.0.2.2:3000/api i get the 
error: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:3000 refused
and if i attempt to reach localhost at 10.0.3.2:3000/api 
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.3.2:3000 timed out

Either way onSuccess is never called. Im not sure why I cant get do a simple login GET request on my local machine. LoopBack is configured to use mongodb as database. i have mongod running and loopback is listening but still nothing connects.

Any ideas?

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
    login.setOnClickListener(loginB);
}

View.OnClickListener loginB = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String username = "TestUserr";
        String password = "password";

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter(getApplicationContext(),"http://10.0.2.2:3000/api");

        UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();
        userRepo.setAdapter(restAdapter);

        Log.i(TAG,"onClicked");
        Log.i(TAG,username + " : " + password);

        userRepo.loginUser(username, password, new UserRepository.LoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AccessToken token, User currentUser) {
                System.out.println("Success: " + token.getUserId() + ":" + currentUser.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Failed");
                Log.e("Chatome", "Login E", t);
            }
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: 10.0.2.2 as a special alias only exists on the emulator.  Are you using a physical device?

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah i was trying to test login on emulator

Comment: did you resolved the issue ?